# Fastest data structure to check if a property within a list of objects matches

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, dictionary, hashset

I've got a list which stores a number of objects.  Each object has a property in the form of a variable.

I'd like to be able to check if any of the items in this list contain a certain property.  Similar to the Dictionary's ContainsKey method.  This data structure is to hold an extremely large amount of values, possibly even millions and I would thus like to use a data structure which can check the properties as fast as possible.

Would Dictionary be the fastest for this job, or are there faster data structures?

**EDIT:**

Here's a quick, small example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
Dictionary<string, Person> persons = new Dictionary<string, Person>(); //where string contains the Person's name

bool isPresent = persons.ContainsKey("Matt");
```

Comment: Where are these millions of records coming from? An IEnumerable<T> against the data source to *query* the data is the fastest. Loading millions of records into memory is not practical. Let databases/NOSQL do the heavy lifting via LINQ.

Comment: Do you know the type and the property in advance. I.e. Are you testing "Order" objects for the "Region" property? Or is it an unknown object for a fixed-name property? Or could it use dynamic? Or if the member isnt fixed, maybe FastMember? Or...? Or...? Please add an example...

Comment: @tawman: Having millions of records in memory can *absolutely* be practical (and blazingly fast) depending on the size of the record. In a previous job I managed to boost performance *hugely* by converting code which was performing a lookup in a database table into an in-memory one, tuned to reduce memory usage. It all depends on context.

Comment: @JonSkeet Very true Jon and I was speaking to the general case since my brain is in MVC mode ATM. Loading millions of records into memory is not typically then. However, I see you point clearly in the broader spectrum of implementation. P.S. Enjoying your C# in Depth book btw +1

Comment: "Each object has a property in the form of a variable." - That sentence doesn't work - variables are something that exist within methods. You can't *have* a property that is a variable. Perhaps post some (pseudo-)code to illustrate what you actually mean

Comment: I've edited my question to present a quick example of what I'm after.

Comment: @tawman stackoverflow uses MVC ... And for some (very specific) parts of stackoverflow we store millions of rows in memory ;)

Comment: @MarcGravell Hehe .. true but SO is the exception and not the rule.

Comment: @tawman not so much, really: code is code is code

Comment: @marcgravell but hardware is hardware is hardware and many organizations don't scale well on the infrastructure side of the equation. I concede your point but code does not always win.

Comment: @tawman we do that *precisely so* we can scale efficiently...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you basically just need a `HashSet<T>` containing all the property values - assuming you *really* just want to know whether it's contained or not.

For example:

```
var allNames = new HashSet<string>(people.Select(person => person.Name));
```

Comment: I've edited my question to present a quick example of what I'm after. Would the HashSet be faster than a Dictionary in my particular case?

Comment: @Sean: Potentially - you may get better cache coherency because there's no "value" to store. It would definitely be more memory efficient (assuming a sensible implementation). More importantly, a set represents what you're interested in (the presence or absence of something) more accurately than a dictionary (which represents a key/value *mapping*).

Comment: When you put it that way, it does sound like it's more suited to my specific problem. As you mentioned, a key/value mapping, although present in my example, is just a means to an end - which can most probably still be illustrated through a HashSet. I'll try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you can load the data into a dictionary once and then query it multiple times, then a dictionary is clearly the fastest possible data structure. If several items can have the same property value, you will have to create a `Dictionary<TKey,List<TValue>>` or to use a LINQ Lookup.

However, if you have to load the list each time you query it, then there is no benefit in using a dictionary. You can detect the right properties while loading the list or, if you are querying a database, then try to load just the required data by using an appropriate where clause.